# Systemic Functional Linguistics - clause boundaries, theme composition

Tags: clauses, syntactic-analysis

Is my analysis correct that the following use of *wh-* question words and *how* is two clauses linked by a conjunction:

> I don't understand || how/why/when/where he did it
>   here's || why I have a problem

Furthermore are these to be considered **textual** themes, while in

> I don't know || what he did
>   I don't know || where he did it
>   I don't know || who did it

*what, where* and *who* would be **ideational** themes?

Comment: I suggest you delete the second part of your post and ask it as a separate question, including what resources you have used in an attempt to answer it yourself.

Comment: What is SFL? Please [edit] to explain.

Comment: Thanks for your help, the clause boundaries issue is certainly tackled in the other post. The other question relates to the composition of themes (the first meaningful element in a clause) in systemic functional linguistics.

Comment: Why would you want to learn functional grammar, a confused meaning-based mish-mash based largely on Michael Halliday's thinking?

Comment: @BillJ. To reduce functionalism to "_a confused meaning-based mish-mash_" does it a considerable disservice. Whether one considers formalism and functionalism as  antagonistic rather than complementary, it does strike me as odd to call into question the desire to learn about functional grammar.